# BlackBerry Manager inheritor scroll issue

Tags: blackberry

I saw only a few questions related BlackBerry, but I think knowledgeable members are just modest:)

The question is: I am implementing a custom manager. Everything is wonderful except for scrolling(In my case it's horizontal). Here is part of my code:

```
public class TemplateSelect extends Manager {
    public static int THUMBNAIL_WIDTH  = 150;
    public static int THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT = 150;

    private int width, height, lastX, sx;

    public TemplateSelect(int w, int h) {
        super(Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
        width = w;
        height = h;     
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getPreferredHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        // Adding templates
        int top = 0, left = 0, deltaLeft = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < getFieldCount(); i++) {
            Template t = (Template) getField(i); 
            layoutChild(t, 0, 0);
            setPositionChild(getField(i), deltaLeft + left, top);

            if (left + THUMBNAIL_WIDTH > Display.getWidth()) {
                left = 0;
                if (top + THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT * 2 > getPreferredHeight()) {
                    deltaLeft += getPreferredHeight();
                    top = 0;
                } else {
                    top += THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT;
                }
            } else {
                left += THUMBNAIL_WIDTH;
            }
        }

        setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {
        if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.DOWN) {
            // Save down click location
            lastX = message.getGlobalX(1);
            sx = lastX;
        } else
        if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.UP) {
            Template t = (Template) getFieldWithFocus();

            int delta;
            if (lastX - message.getGlobalX(1) > 0) {
                delta = t.getX() + getPreferredWidth();
            } else {
                delta = t.getX() - getPreferredWidth();
            }

            Template next = (Template) getField(getFieldAtLocation(delta, t.getY()));
            if (next != null) {
                next.setFocus();
            } else {
                Dialog.inform("NULL");
            }
        } else 
            if (message.getEvent() == TouchEvent.MOVE) {
                lastX = sx;
                setHorizontalScroll(getHorizontalScroll() + sx - message.getGlobalX(1), true);
                System.out.println(getHorizontalScroll());
                sx = message.getX(1);
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am calling setHorizontalScroll, after that immediately checking its value, but it remains equal to zero ( and scrolling does not occur.

What I did not consider? What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by breaking my component on pages and putting them into `HorizontalFieldManager`

Answer (score 0):

`setHorizontalScroll(getHorizontalScroll() + sx - message.getGlobalX(1), true);`

The second argument to true activate the animation. So it cannot have the expected scroll amount immediately.

If you code for OS 6 and 7, I'd advice to let the standard scrolling behavior and activate your touchEvent code with preprocessors

Comment: How can I let the standard scrolling behaviour? The point is that if I inherited from VerticalFieldManager  - scrolling in my code works, but at the same time it does not work correctly layout.